# Wrapping ReaderWriterLockSlim in an IDisposable handler

Tags: c#, multithreading, readerwriterlockslim

All,

It seems really natural to me to use the IDisposable pattern to control a ReaderWriterLockSlim lock, since it allows locks to be cleaned up without the extra cruft of a try/catch block.  I notice that there is nothing in the BCL to take care of this common(ish) task, so I wonder if my code below is really naive?  I see some other questions on SO related to this general area, but nothing that tackles the appropriateness of this idea head-on.

The question also is not about whether the Dispose() method on ReaderWriterLockSlim object should be called, just the wrapper.

```
public class LockWrapper : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim @lock;
    private readonly bool writeRequired;

    public LockWrapper(ReaderWriterLockSlim @lock, bool writeRequired)
    {
        this.@lock = @lock;
        this.writeRequired = writeRequired;

        if (writeRequired)
        {
            @lock.EnterWriteLock();
        }
        else
        {
            @lock.EnterReadLock();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (writeRequired && @lock.IsWriteLockHeld)
        {
            @lock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
        else if (@lock.IsReadLockHeld)
        {
            @lock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var @lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim(LockRecursionPolicy.SupportsRecursion);
using(var lockWrapper = new LockWrapper(@lock, true))
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: `using` based locks interact badly with thread abortion. But since you shouldn't abort them in the first place, it's not that bad.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Is that because the Dispose() method won't be called?

Comment: Because there is a time window between the locking and the entering of the try-block where a thread abortion will not release the lock.

Comment: If you want to write these as an answer, i'd be happy to flag it as the answer.

Comment: If I recall correctly, only some architectures have the issue. Still there is no warranty on the CLR part. You can mitigate the problem by adding a finalizer in your IDisposable wrapper to handle any leak... Still, don't abort your threads anyway.

Comment: May I ask where you found that out?

Comment: @JonBates https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix/